# Objective-C Remove ANSI Color Control Codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex, tty

I'm building an iOS application that communicates with a remote server. In this case, I'm executing commands using SSH, however, the response coming back from the server is coming in the form of what appears to be hexadecimal. My delegate function for handling responses from a remote server takes the response argument as an NSString, however, this is the content of the string returned (command executed was "ls /" )

```
ls /\r\n\x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mbin\x1b[0m    \x1b[01;34mdev\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;36minitrd.img\x1b[0m            \x1b[01;34mlib64\x1b[0m       \x1b[01;34mmnt\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;34mroot\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34msrv\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34musr\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b[01;34mboot\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;34metc\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;36minitrd.img.old\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34mlost+found\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34mopt\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;34mrun\x1b[0m   \x1b[01;34msys\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34mvar\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b[01;34mcdrom\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34mhome\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34mlib\x1b[0m             \x1b[01;34mmedia\x1b[0m       \x1b[01;34mproc\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;34msbin\x1b[0m  \x1b[30;42mtmp\x1b[0m  \x1b[01;36mvmlinuz\x1b[0m'
```

If this is in fact hexadecimal, how to I convert this back to a readable string for display purposes? If it's not hexadecimal, does anyone know what it is?

EDIT:

Since this is ANSI Color Control Codes, what's the best method to remove them?

Comment: Those are ANSI coloring control codes.

Comment: Yeah, you want to set your terminal type to be something super plain.  There should be some parameter you can pass to however you're setting up the SSH connection.  Try vt100?

Comment: Instead of running `ls /`, run `ls --no-color /`.

Comment: or `ls --color=never`, depending on your version of `ls`.

Comment: vt100 still returns with the ANSI coloring control codes. I can't for testing purposes ls --no-color would work, but ultimately this will be a terminal emulator functionality, which I can't assume every user will use the --no-color argument

Comment: How could I go about removing the coloring codes?

Comment: Read the data into an `NSMutableData` and log that. Then you will see the actuial bytes--in hex. Hex is a display format, data is just bytes.

Comment: If you can post code I'll accept as the answer. Thanks

Comment: You can also parse them and do the right thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: http://hasseg.org/ansiEscapeHelper/ Some minor modifications may have to be applied (like NSColor -> UIColor), etc, since it's for Mac OS X.

Comment: Yeah already looked at the ansiEscapeHelper. Only works with Cocoa. I'm building an iOS application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepend "\" to the beginning of the command

```
$ \ls
```

or provide handling for the escape sequences (strip, display)

Comment: You sir, are a saint and a scholar. Much Appreciated!